# Dynamic Text doesn't show up through code

Tags: actionscript-3

if I make a dynamic text on the stage, name it something like "output"

And I write in the enterframe.

```
output.text = "Something";
```

It doesn't even show up in the stage, and the text box is blank.

Comment: Did you embed the font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to embed the fonts in dynamic textfield. You can find detailed information regarding embedding fonts [in here](http://www.logicmanialab.com/2011/03/font-embedding-in-flash-cs5.html). It's bit old but it will work.

Comment: its odd, sometimes it doesnt work at all, sometimes it works even without embedding. must be a glitch.